# Embedding React app as a widget with Javascript is failing with different messages on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, widget, create-react-app

Following the steps on this [site](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-two-easiest-ways-to-share-your-reactjs-project-as-a-widget-971dfef66d98) I'm able to embed a react app as a widget at another site with iframe:

```
<html>
  <iframe src="http://localhost:3000"><iframe>
</html>
```

Embedding with Javascript (the second method) is failing with the following error message on Firefox:

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.dbfc58d6.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

Following is my code to embed the react app:

```
<html lang="en">    
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.dbfc58d6.chunk.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

I can confirm that the js source I specified is correct and running:
[image]

On Chrome, the warning message is displayed as below:

```
index.html:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://localhost/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
index.html:10 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.dbfc58d6.chunk.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Seeking guidance to solve this. Thank you for reading.

Update:
Referring to @Thai's answer, I'm specifying my source file as the one generated by the react build operation. How can I specify the right js file to solve my issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with assistance - the issue was due to the way I was creating the build.

We can't use the default build tool that comes with CRA. Use [rescripts/cli](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) instead.

1. Install @rescripts/cli as a dev dependency:

`npm install @rescripts/cli --save-dev`

2. Update package.json "scripts" to run with 'rescripts':

   `"scripts": {
       "start": "rescripts start",
       "build": "rescripts build",
       "test": "rescripts test",
       "eject": "rescripts eject"
     },`
3. Build your app with

`npm run buiild`

4. Embed the app with:

   `<script src="https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: A file called rescript.js must be created first prior to running build.

Answer (score 2):

> I can confirm that the js source I specified is correct and running

Thanks for posting that screenshot, because it is crucial to figuring out what the problem is. Contrary to what you said, the JS source is not correct. Your JavaScript source is just a text file, and it cannot run on its own inside a browser.

This means that when you view the JavaScript source file, you should see the source code, and not a working application.

[image: If the URL of the JavaScript file is correct you should see JavaScript code instead of a working application]

However in your screenshot it shows the actual application and not the JavaScript source.

[image: Browser screenshot]

What you're actually getting is an HTML page. Your development server probably serves this page when a file you requested couldn’t be found. So it serves the index page as a fallback.

Next time, when confirming if something is correct, may I suggest that you try intentionally making it incorrect, and then see if the result differs?

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The src I specified was the result of my build as I've updated on my question. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in calling the widget. Could you elaborate on your answer?